# always ensuring a slash before the hash in ember.js

Tags: iis, ember.js, ember-data

This may be platform-agnostic but I'll include the server I'm running on.

I'm running into an issue hosting an ember.js site within a directory in IIS.

Let's say I would like to host the site at `http://localhost/myapp`.

I have a RESTAdapter with the host set to "api" so that requests will go to `localhost/myapp/api`. If I don't do this, then the RESTAdapter will request from `localhost/api`.

I have a problem when I navigate to `localhost/myapp` and follow a link-to to a model. It ends up looking like `localhost/myapp#/model` which under the hood breaks the api call--it ends up calling `localhost/api` again (I'm assuming because it truncates everything after the last slash and before the hash). I don't have any problems if I navigate to `localhost/myapp/` and take the same actions--the url becomes `localhost/myapp/#/model` which results in the RESTAdapter call going to `/myapp/api/model`.

Is this a problem with how I'm configuring the RESTAdapter or that I'm not forcing a trailing slash when going to the app root? I'd like to find out how to solve this problem requiring as little ad-hoc configuration as possible (for example explicitly defining myapp as the namespace is not optimal--it could differ from environment to environment and requires custom build steps). Is there a way to always ensure that '/' routes to 'myapp/' or that when a hash is appended it will put '/' in the url if it doesn't already end in it? Or is this something that is going to have to be configured on the server?

Comment: This is a common problem, especially when you can't derive a path relatively or absolutely.  In that case you're forced to create an ad-hoc relationship of sorts.  Either you explicitly define in one place an application path as your root, or you define logic that assumes an application path exists and derives the path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you can really only figure it out server-side, the most straightforward way I found to accomplish this was having the server render the path in markup assigning it to a global Javascript variable that my other scripts referenced.